# QSerialPort: Reading incorrect values

Tags: c++, qt

I'm writing a program to read from QSerialPort. The program seems to work about 85% of the time however there's a strange situation occurring in which nonsense is being read into my buffer.

Sometimes the program unexpectedly crashes on startup due to a massive buffer of x00 values. This is not the response from my module and ONLY seems to happen occasionally on startup.

I think there's a problem in the way i'm deleting my instance of QSerialPort but cannot seem to find it.

I also noticed QSerialPort has a function "sendBreak" which seems to be doing what my program is (sending massive steam of x00/x00/x00).

My question is: has anyone encountered this before? Is there some strange possibility my QSerialPort::read() function is somehow executing a "sendBreak"? Or does this look more likely to be an issue with deleting instances/pointers (reading data from address that wasn't deconstructed properly)?

Constructor:

```
 serial = new QSerialPort;
    serial->setPortName("/dev/ttyUSB0");
    serial->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600); // 9600
    serial->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serial->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    serial->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    serial->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    serial->open(QSerialPort::ReadWrite);
    serial->clear(QSerialPort::AllDirections);
```

Reading port:

```
readData.append(serial->read(50));
```

Destructor:

```
serial->clear(QSerialPort::AllDirections);
serial->close();
delete serial;
```

I realise this could be quite a generic question, but i currently cannot find the problem so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Many things can got wrong. Do you check before the first read if the serial port is open? Are you using waitForReadyRead?

Comment: Sending NULLs and a 'break' are not the same. A 'break' is when the line goes to zero for some extended period of time (more than a few character times). There are no start-bits in a break, so the receiver should not see any characters, even NULLs. To see a string of NULL characters, each character would need an associated start-bit. Noise (manifested as false start-bits) could cause your problem, or a serial-port driver issue, or the other end could indeed be sending a string of NULLs.

Comment: I am using readyRead() to know when to read from the port, however not using waitForReadyRead(). I'm not checking if the serialport is open first, however I will get an error thrown if it is not open (which I don't get). Thank-you re info on break, didn't understand the operation. I don't seem to have a driver issue that I can tell of and the module should not send this steam of data (contacted manufacturer regarding this). After these comments I'm inclined to think it could be a readyRead() issue... I've heard it can be problematic.

Comment: Hi, i've been testing the program and found the associated errors. Opening serial port on first try works 90% of the time, however if not shut down correctly the port opening will fail on next start. I only get these errors when reopening port: "Permission error while locking the device" with code 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for what it's worth I found the issue.

After re-reading Qt documentation on QSerialPort and specifically the read() functions it says:

"This function has no way of reporting errors; returning an empty QByteArray can mean either that no data was currently available for reading, or that an error occurred."

What seems to have been happening is that my readyRead() signal is getting fired even when I didn't have data to be read?! A simple if statement checking for bytesAvailable() in my readPort method means I only read when I have data waiting to be read.

I'm quite surprised that this function reads regardless and feel this issue could've been highlighted/dealt with better....

EDIT: Found the real issue to this problem. I was using readData.resize() which was clearing the array without instantiating it. Therefore as I was clearing it before reading (but not initialised) it was reading an address.